# how to pass multiple unique identifiers to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parameterizing an SQL IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause)

Hi how can we send multiple uniqueidentifiers to a stored procedure.

Ex:

```
Create procedure showall
(@empids uniqueidentifier(50) )
as
select * from emp where empid in (@empid)
```

like this?

Comment: With a split function or table valued param, lots of dups; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: I want to pass multiple uniqueidentifier types not strings. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, correctly formatted guids in strings are interchangeable with uniqueidentifier

Answer (score 2):

As Diego mentioned already, you can use a table valued parameter. Here is an example of how you could use a table valued parameter to inner join against your passed list, thus filtering your list accordingly.

```
    create procedure showall
    (
     @empids uniqueidentifier(50)
    ,@myTableVariable mySchema.myTableType readonly
    )
as 
    select
        *
    from
        emp e
        inner join @myTableVariable m
        on e.empids = m.empids

    --where
    --  empid in ( @empid )
```

If you never have used a table valued parameter before it can be a little confusing. You need to create a [user defined table type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).  As the section on the creation shows, once you've created the table structure you could go back and then define your parameter type as a table value parameter.

```
create type mySchema.myTableName as table
( empids uniqueidentifier)
```

Then you reference it in the parameter clause as above in the first code sample. Hope this helps, it confused me the first time I used it, but it sure can be handy and reduce trips from an application.

Answer (score 0):

multiple parameters can be passed as a comma (or any other symbol) separated string and then treated inside the proc or as a [table-valued parameter](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)